# Firebase database ref not listening to updates in value

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to trigger a function based on data in a Firebase ref being updated.  I have a ref called 'articles' that I push articles to, and each individual article has a child ref called 'upVotes'.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to catch upvotes happening.  I'm trying with this:

```
articlesRef.on('child_added', function(data) {
    var upVoteRef = database.ref('articles/' + data.key + '/upVotes/');
    upVoteRef.on('child_changed', function(childData){
        console.log(childData.val())

    });
    });
```

Which is in the top scope of my file.  It returns the number of votes when the page is loaded, but isn't triggered when the number of votes changes.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is `upVotes` a number or a list of votes?

Comment: @MichaelBleigh  It's a number

Comment: @MichaelBleigh  I just realized that is should be 'value' instead of 'child_changed'.  That was my problem, thanks.